# Arduino Memory Leakage

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, arduino

I am running some code on Pinoccio which is a fork of Arduino. I am leaking memory in the following code below and I've included the memory footprint of my program running vs time.

I've spent the last couple of hours debugging why my memory is slowly leaking away so I've decided to just give this forum a shot.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Scout.h>
#include <GS.h>
#include <bitlash.h>
#include <lwm.h>
#include <js0n.h>
#include <QueueArray.h>
#include <Oyoroi.h>
#include <aJSON.h>
#include <MemoryFree.h>


#define SERVER_LOCATION "1.2.3.4"
#define SERVER_PORT 5000

int INTERVAL_QUERY_SERVER = 10000;

struct OMessage {
  int scoutId;
  String message;
  int messageKey;
};

QueueArray<OMessage*> queue;
GSTcpClient *clientPtr;
GSModule *gsPtr;

bool isOyoroiVerbose = 0;


void setup() {
  Scout.setup("Custom", "Unknown", -1);
  Serial.begin(115200);

  Shell.isVerbose = false;
  Shell.eval("rm *");      // Clean up previous installations
  Shell.eval("hq.verbose(0)");
  Shell.eval("events.verbose(0)");
  Shell.eval("mesh.verbose(0)");

  addBitlashFunction("oyoroi.verbose", (bitlash_function) oyoroiVerbose);
  Shell.eval("oyoroi.verbose(1)");

  queue.setPrinter(Serial);

  addBitlashFunction("oyoroi.queue", (bitlash_function) oyoroiQueue);
  addBitlashFunction("oyoroi.connect", (bitlash_function) oyoroiConnect);

  // Do not use oyoroi.queue(arg(1), key.print(arg(2))) here because key.print
  // returns 1 when it has executed successfully.
  Shell.eval( "function on.message.scout { oyoroi.queue(arg(1), arg(2)) }");

  gsPtr = &pinoccio::WifiModule::instance.bp()->gs;
  // if you don't use new it will be deleted out of scope
  clientPtr = new GSTcpClient(*gsPtr);
}


long last = 0;

void loop() {
  Scout.loop();

  long now = millis();
  if (now - last > INTERVAL_QUERY_SERVER) {
    last = now;
    oyoroiConnect();
  } else if (now < last) {    // millis resets
    last = now;
  }
}


numvar oyoroiVerbose(void) {
  if (!checkArgs(1, F("usage: oyoroi.verbose(flag)"))) {
    return 0;
  }
  isOyoroiVerbose = getarg(1);
  return 1;
}


numvar oyoroiQueue(void) {
  if (isOyoroiVerbose) {
    Serial.print("oyoroi.queue: scoutId:");
    Serial.print(getarg(1));
    Serial.print(" message:");
    // do not use getstringarg
    Serial.print(keyGet(getarg(2)));
    Serial.print(" free-memory:");
    Serial.println(freeMemory());
  }
  OMessage *m = new OMessage();
  m->scoutId = getarg(1);
  m->message = keyGet(getarg(2));
  m->messageKey = getarg(2);
  queue.enqueue(m);
}


String getPostData(void) {
  Serial.print("getPostData - 1: "); Serial.println(freeMemory());
  aJsonObject *root = aJson.createObject();
  aJsonObject *array = aJson.createArray();
  aJson.addItemToObject(root, "data", array);
  int i=queue.count();

  Serial.print("getPostData - 2: "); Serial.println(freeMemory());
  while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
    OMessage *m = queue.dequeue();
    aJsonObject *node = aJson.createObject();

    aJson.addNumberToObject(node, "scoutId", m->scoutId);

    char charBuf[10];
    m->message.toCharArray(charBuf, 10);
    aJson.addStringToObject(node, "message", charBuf);

    aJson.addItemToArray(array, node);

    // Don't forget to free up our used memory!
    keyFree(m->messageKey);
    delete(m);
  }
  Serial.print("getPostData - 3: "); Serial.println(freeMemory());
  char *json_String = aJson.print(root);

  Serial.print("getPostData - 4: "); Serial.println(freeMemory());
  while (i>0) {
    aJson.deleteItemFromArray(array, i--);
  }
  aJson.deleteItemFromObject(root, "data");
  aJson.deleteItem(root);
  Serial.print("getPostData - 5: "); Serial.println(freeMemory());

  return json_String;
}


numvar oyoroiConnect(void) {
  Serial.print("oyoroiConnect - 1: "); Serial.println(freeMemory());

  if (queue.isEmpty()) {
    if (isOyoroiVerbose)
      Serial.println("Queue is empty.");
    return 0;
  }

  if (!gsPtr->isAssociated()) {
    if (isOyoroiVerbose)
      Serial.println("GSModule not associated yet.");
    return 0;
  }

  IPAddress ip;
  char* url = SERVER_LOCATION;

  if (!gsPtr->parseIpAddress(&ip, url)) {
    ip = gsPtr->dnsLookup(url);

    if (ip == INADDR_NONE) {
      if (isOyoroiVerbose)  {
        Serial.print(F("Failed to resolve "));
        Serial.println(url);
      }
      return 0;
    }
  }

  if (!clientPtr->connect(ip, SERVER_PORT)) {
    Serial.print(F("ERROR - Connection to "));
    Serial.print(url);
    Serial.print(F(":"));
    Serial.print(SERVER_PORT);
    Serial.println(F(" failed."));
    return 0;
  }

  if (isOyoroiVerbose)
    Serial.println("Client successfully connected to server");
  clientPtr->println(F("POST / HTTP/1.1"));
  clientPtr->println(F("User-Agent: pinoccio"));

  clientPtr->print(F("Host: "));
  clientPtr->print(SERVER_LOCATION);
  clientPtr->print(":");
  clientPtr->println(SERVER_PORT);

  clientPtr->println("Connection: close");

  String postData = getPostData();
  Serial.print("oyoroiConnect - 2: "); Serial.println(freeMemory());

  clientPtr->print("Content-Length: ");
  clientPtr->println(postData.length());
  clientPtr->println("Content-type: application/json");
  clientPtr->println();

  clientPtr->println(postData);

  clientPtr->println();
  clientPtr->flush();

  while (clientPtr->connected()) {
    if (clientPtr->available()) {
      clientPtr->read();
    } else {
      Scout.loop();
    }
  }

  Serial.print("oyoroiConnect - 3: "); Serial.println(freeMemory());

  return 1;
}
```

And the log:

```
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:15363
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.26 free-memory:15338
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:15316
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:15288
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.26 free-memory:15113
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:15117
oyoroiConnect - 1: 15401
Client successfully connected to server
getPostData - 1: 15332
getPostData - 2: 15294
getPostData - 3: 14974
getPostData - 4: 14716
getPostData - 5: 15211
oyoroiConnect - 2: 15063
oyoroiConnect - 3: 15098
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:14974
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.26 free-memory:14950
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:14930
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:14904
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.26 free-memory:14882
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:14853
oyoroiConnect - 1: 15171
Client successfully connected to server
getPostData - 1: 15102
getPostData - 2: 15064
getPostData - 3: 14753
getPostData - 4: 14495
getPostData - 5: 14988
oyoroiConnect - 2: 14840
oyoroiConnect - 3: 14840
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:14716
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.26 free-memory:14692
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:14672
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:14646
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:14624
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:14595
oyoroiConnect - 1: 14913
Client successfully connected to server
getPostData - 1: 14844
getPostData - 2: 14806
getPostData - 3: 14495
getPostData - 4: 14237
getPostData - 5: 14730
oyoroiConnect - 2: 14582
oyoroiConnect - 3: 14582
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:14458
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.26 free-memory:14434
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:14414
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:14388
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:14366
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:14337
oyoroiConnect - 1: 14655
Client successfully connected to server
getPostData - 1: 14586
getPostData - 2: 14548
getPostData - 3: 14237
getPostData - 4: 13979
getPostData - 5: 14472
oyoroiConnect - 2: 14324
oyoroiConnect - 3: 14324
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:14200
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:14176
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:14156
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:14130
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.26 free-memory:14108
oyoroiConnect - 1: 14419
Client successfully connected to server
getPostData - 1: 14350
getPostData - 2: 14312
getPostData - 3: 14052
getPostData - 4: 13794
getPostData - 5: 14214
oyoroiConnect - 2: 14100
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:13753
oyoroiConnect - 3: 14078
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:13918
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:13898
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:13872
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:13850
oyoroiConnect - 1: 14161
Client successfully connected to server
getPostData - 1: 14092
getPostData - 2: 14054
getPostData - 3: 13794
getPostData - 4: 13536
getPostData - 5: 13956
oyoroiConnect - 2: 13842
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.26 free-memory:13495
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:13471
oyoroiConnect - 3: 13798
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:13640
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:13614
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:13592
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:13563
oyoroiConnect - 1: 13881
Client successfully connected to server
getPostData - 1: 13812
getPostData - 2: 13774
getPostData - 3: 13463
getPostData - 4: 13205
getPostData - 5: 13698
oyoroiConnect - 2: 13550
oyoroiConnect - 3: 13550
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:13426
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:13402
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:13382
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:13356
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:13334
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:13305
oyoroiConnect - 1: 13623
Client successfully connected to server
getPostData - 1: 13554
getPostData - 2: 13516
getPostData - 3: 13205
getPostData - 4: 12947
getPostData - 5: 13440
oyoroiConnect - 2: 13292
oyoroiConnect - 3: 13292
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:13168
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:13144
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:13124
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:13098
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:13076
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:13047
oyoroiConnect - 1: 13365
Client successfully connected to server
getPostData - 1: 13296
getPostData - 2: 13258
getPostData - 3: 12947
getPostData - 4: 12689
getPostData - 5: 13182
oyoroiConnect - 2: 13034
oyoroiConnect - 3: 13034
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.26 free-memory:12910
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:12886
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:12866
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:12840
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:12818
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:12789
oyoroiConnect - 1: 13107
Client successfully connected to server
getPostData - 1: 13038
getPostData - 2: 13000
getPostData - 3: 12689
getPostData - 4: 12431
getPostData - 5: 12924
oyoroiConnect - 2: 12776
oyoroiConnect - 3: 12776
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.26 free-memory:12652
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:12628
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:12608
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.26 free-memory:12582
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:12560
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:12531
oyoroiConnect - 1: 12849
Client successfully connected to server
getPostData - 1: 12780
getPostData - 2: 12742
getPostData - 3: 12431
getPostData - 4: 12173
getPostData - 5: 12666
oyoroiConnect - 2: 12518
oyoroiConnect - 3: 12518
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.26 free-memory:12394
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:12370
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:12350
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.26 free-memory:12324
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:12302
oyoroiConnect - 1: 12613
Client successfully connected to server
getPostData - 1: 12544
getPostData - 2: 12506
getPostData - 3: 12246
getPostData - 4: 11988
getPostData - 5: 12408
oyoroiConnect - 2: 12294
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:11947
oyoroiConnect - 3: 12272
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.26 free-memory:12112
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:12092
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:12066
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:11939
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:11910
oyoroiConnect - 1: 12228
Client successfully connected to server
getPostData - 1: 12159
getPostData - 2: 12121
getPostData - 3: 11800
getPostData - 4: 11542
getPostData - 5: 12037
oyoroiConnect - 2: 11889
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:11542
oyoroiConnect - 3: 11867
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:11741
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:11721
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:11695
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.26 free-memory:11673
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:11643
oyoroiConnect - 1: 11959
Client successfully connected to server
getPostData - 1: 11890
getPostData - 2: 11852
getPostData - 3: 11536
getPostData - 4: 11278
getPostData - 5: 11779
oyoroiConnect - 2: 11631
oyoroiConnect - 3: 11631
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:11507
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.26 free-memory:11483
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:11463
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:11437
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:11415
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:11385
oyoroiConnect - 1: 11701
Client successfully connected to server
getPostData - 1: 11632
getPostData - 2: 11594
getPostData - 3: 11278
getPostData - 4: 11020
getPostData - 5: 11521
oyoroiConnect - 2: 11373
oyoroiConnect - 3: 11373
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:11249
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:11225
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:11205
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:11179
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.26 free-memory:11157
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:11127
oyoroiConnect - 1: 11443
Client successfully connected to server
getPostData - 1: 11374
getPostData - 2: 11336
getPostData - 3: 11020
getPostData - 4: 10762
getPostData - 5: 11263
oyoroiConnect - 2: 11115
oyoroiConnect - 3: 11115
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:10991
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.26 free-memory:10967
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:10947
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:10921
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.26 free-memory:10899
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:10869
oyoroiConnect - 1: 11185
Client successfully connected to server
getPostData - 1: 11116
getPostData - 2: 11078
getPostData - 3: 10762
getPostData - 4: 10504
getPostData - 5: 11005
oyoroiConnect - 2: 10857
oyoroiConnect - 3: 10857
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:10733
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:10709
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:10689
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:10663
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:10641
oyoroiConnect - 1: 10952
Client successfully connected to server
getPostData - 1: 10883
getPostData - 2: 10845
getPostData - 3: 10577
getPostData - 4: 10319
getPostData - 5: 10747
oyoroiConnect - 2: 10633
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:10286
oyoroiConnect - 3: 10611
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:10451
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.26 free-memory:10431
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:10405
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:10383
oyoroiConnect - 1: 10694
Client successfully connected to server
getPostData - 1: 10625
getPostData - 2: 10587
getPostData - 3: 10319
getPostData - 4: 10061
getPostData - 5: 10489
oyoroiConnect - 2: 10375
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.26 free-memory:10028
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:10004
oyoroiConnect - 3: 10331
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:10173
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.26 free-memory:10147
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:10125
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:10095
oyoroiConnect - 1: 10411
Client successfully connected to server
getPostData - 1: 10342
getPostData - 2: 10304
getPostData - 3: 9988
getPostData - 4: 9730
getPostData - 5: 10231
oyoroiConnect - 2: 10083
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:9736
oyoroiConnect - 3: 10061
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:9935
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:9915
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.26 free-memory:9889
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:9867
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:9837
oyoroiConnect - 1: 10153
Client successfully connected to server
getPostData - 1: 10084
getPostData - 2: 10046
getPostData - 3: 9730
getPostData - 4: 9472
getPostData - 5: 9973
oyoroiConnect - 2: 9825
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.26 free-memory:9478
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:9454
oyoroiConnect - 3: 9781
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:9657
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:9631
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:9609
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:9579
oyoroiConnect - 1: 9895
Client successfully connected to server
getPostData - 1: 9826
getPostData - 2: 9788
getPostData - 3: 9472
getPostData - 4: 9214
getPostData - 5: 9715
oyoroiConnect - 2: 9567
oyoroiConnect - 3: 9567
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:9443
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:9419
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:9399
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.26 free-memory:9373
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:9351
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:9321
oyoroiConnect - 1: 9637
Client successfully connected to server
getPostData - 1: 9568
getPostData - 2: 9530
getPostData - 3: 9214
getPostData - 4: 8956
getPostData - 5: 9457
oyoroiConnect - 2: 9309
oyoroiConnect - 3: 9309
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.26 free-memory:9185
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:9161
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:9141
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:9115
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:9093
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:9063
oyoroiConnect - 1: 9379
Client successfully connected to server
getPostData - 1: 9310
getPostData - 2: 9272
getPostData - 3: 8956
getPostData - 4: 8698
getPostData - 5: 9199
oyoroiConnect - 2: 9051
oyoroiConnect - 3: 9051
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:8927
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:8903
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:8883
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:8857
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:8835
oyoroiConnect - 1: 9146
Client successfully connected to server
getPostData - 1: 9077
getPostData - 2: 9039
getPostData - 3: 8771
getPostData - 4: 8513
getPostData - 5: 8941
oyoroiConnect - 2: 8827
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:8480
oyoroiConnect - 3: 8805
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:8645
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:8625
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:8599
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.26 free-memory:8577
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:8547
oyoroiConnect - 1: 8863
Client successfully connected to server
getPostData - 1: 8794
getPostData - 2: 8756
getPostData - 3: 8440
getPostData - 4: 8182
getPostData - 5: 8683
oyoroiConnect - 2: 8535
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:8188
oyoroiConnect - 3: 8513
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:8387
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:8367
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:8341
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.26 free-memory:8319
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:8289
oyoroiConnect - 1: 8605
Client successfully connected to server
getPostData - 1: 8536
getPostData - 2: 8498
getPostData - 3: 8182
getPostData - 4: 7924
getPostData - 5: 8425
oyoroiConnect - 2: 8277
oyoroiConnect - 3: 8277
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:8153
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.26 free-memory:8129
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:8109
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:8083
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:8061
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:8031
oyoroiConnect - 1: 8347
Client successfully connected to server
getPostData - 1: 8278
getPostData - 2: 8240
getPostData - 3: 7924
getPostData - 4: 7666
getPostData - 5: 8167
oyoroiConnect - 2: 8019
oyoroiConnect - 3: 8019
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:7895
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.26 free-memory:7871
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:7851
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:7825
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.26 free-memory:7803
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:7773
oyoroiConnect - 1: 8089
Client successfully connected to server
getPostData - 1: 8020
getPostData - 2: 7982
getPostData - 3: 7666
getPostData - 4: 7408
getPostData - 5: 7909
oyoroiConnect - 2: 7761
oyoroiConnect - 3: 7761
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:7637
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.26 free-memory:7613
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:7593
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:7567
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.26 free-memory:7545
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:7515
oyoroiConnect - 1: 7831
Client successfully connected to server
getPostData - 1: 7762
getPostData - 2: 7724
getPostData - 3: 7408
getPostData - 4: 7150
getPostData - 5: 7651
oyoroiConnect - 2: 7503
oyoroiConnect - 3: 7503
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:7379
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.26 free-memory:7355
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:7335
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:7309
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.26 free-memory:7272
oyoroiConnect - 1: 7583
Client successfully connected to server
getPostData - 1: 7514
getPostData - 2: 7476
getPostData - 3: 7211
getPostData - 4: 6953
getPostData - 5: 7378
oyoroiConnect - 2: 7264
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:6915
oyoroiConnect - 3: 7254
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:7094
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:7072
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:7046
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:7024
oyoroiConnect - 1: 7337
Client successfully connected to server
getPostData - 1: 7268
getPostData - 2: 7231
getPostData - 3: 6971
getPostData - 4: 6713
getPostData - 5: 7135
oyoroiConnect - 2: 7021
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.26 free-memory:6674
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:6650
oyoroiConnect - 3: 6977
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:6819
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.26 free-memory:6793
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:6771
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:6741
oyoroiConnect - 1: 7057
Client successfully connected to server
getPostData - 1: 6988
getPostData - 2: 6950
getPostData - 3: 6634
getPostData - 4: 6376
getPostData - 5: 6877
oyoroiConnect - 2: 6729
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.26 free-memory:6382
oyoroiConnect - 3: 6707
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:6581
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:6561
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.26 free-memory:6535
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:6513
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:6483
oyoroiConnect - 1: 6799
Client successfully connected to server
getPostData - 1: 6730
getPostData - 2: 6692
getPostData - 3: 6376
getPostData - 4: 6118
getPostData - 5: 6619
oyoroiConnect - 2: 6471
oyoroiConnect - 3: 6471
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.26 free-memory:6347
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:6323
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:6303
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:4 message:ph=4.26 free-memory:6277
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:3 message:ph=4.28 free-memory:6255
oyoroi.queue: scoutId:2 message:ph=5.59 free-memory:6225
oyoroiConnect - 1: 6541
Client successfully connected to server
getPostData - 1: 6472
getPostData - 2: 6434
getPostData - 3: 6118
getPostData - 4: 5860
getPostData - 5: 6361
oyoroiConnect - 2: 6213
oyoroiConnect - 3: 6213
...
```

I don't really know what's causing this leak so if anyone can come up with some suggestions I would really appreciate your help

Answer (score 6):

The best advice someone gave me for resource constrained embedded systems is:

> Stay off the heap.

You may not be leaking memory, you are likely just fragmenting it.  The program you show is allocating and deallocating structures on a FIFO queue.  That pattern has poor chance operating robustly.  When a second object is added to the heap and put on the queue, it has buried the first object on the heap.  When the head of the Q is processed, the code does delete() the first objects allocation, but that leaves a hole in memory.  If the third object cannot fit in the hole, then that third object moves to the unused space.

For any application that you intend to run a fixed task and hopefully run that forever, make one time memory allocations and reuse.  In other words, there is no operating system or huge runtime library to support your application: you must manage the memory.

Allocate a fixed pool of N objects

```
struct OMessage {
  int scoutId;
  char message[50];
  int messageKey;
};

const int sizePool = 10;
OMessage pool[10];
int ixNext = 0;
int ixHead = -1;
```

This fixed allocation is now also your queue.  You manage the head and tail.  When you "add" and object to the queue, you fill in the structure and adjust the indexes:

```
// detect full queue if ixNext = ixHead and reject addition
pool[ixNext].scoutId = ...
pool[ixNext].messageKey = ...
ixNext += 1;
ixNext = ixNext % sizePool;
```

When you "pull" and item from the queue, you just move the index:

```
if(ixHead >= 0) {
  do something with pool[ixHead]
  ixHead += 1;
  ixHead = ixHead % sizePool;
  // detect if head = tail and mark q empty
}
```

With the fixed memory allocation, as long as your program starts, you can be certain it will never run out of memory.